# Error in inner matrix dimensions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I was trying to correct the below code but did not succeed .. Matlab says :

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in 
Atten = a*l*f;
```

Here is the code

```
a=[0.6 1.89 4.1 0.9 0.8 3]; 
l=[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5];  
f=[1000000:4000000:21000000]; 
Atten = a*l*f; 
plot(f,Atten)
```

I even tried with `l=[0.4];` but it did not work
How to correct the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it's more a mathematical problem than a programming error.

You're trying to multiply 3 `[1x6]` matrix, of course it's not possible.

Perhaps that you want this operation

```
[1x6]*[6x1]*[1x6] = [1x6]
```

instead of

```
[1x6]*[1x6]*[1x6] = Impossible
```

In that case you can use this operator `.'` to transpose your matrix:

```
Atten = a*l.'*f; 

result:
5.6450e+06   2.8225e+07   5.0805e+07   7.3385e+07   9.5965e+07   1.1855e+08
```

In that situation `l.'` will be a `[6x1]` matrix and the operation is now possible

More information about this operator: [Tranpose vectore or matrix](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in your matrices dimensions.
Make sure to multiply matrices with right dimensions.

You can use the `.'` operator to transpose a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply element-wise, you can use `.` in front of the `*`